# How can I get all date this year from first day to today?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get all date from the start of this year to today in a "%Y-%m-%d" format, is there more easy way to get it like `daterange("2019-01-01", "2019-05-17")` or something?

Here is my trial, but I don't think it is pythonic

```py
import datetime

def get_all_date_from_now_this_year():
    date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    day_today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("{}-01-01".format(day_today.year), date_format).date()
    days_num  = (day_today - start_date).days

    count = 0
    all_date_list = []
    while count < days_num:
        date = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=count)) .strftime(date_format)
        count += 1
        all_date_list.append(date)

    return all_date_list


r_l = get_all_date_from_now_this_year()
```

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
import pandas as pd
date_list=pd.date_range("2019-01-01","2019-05-17")
```

OUTPUT:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04',
               '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08',
               '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10',
               ...
               '2019-05-08', '2019-05-09', '2019-05-10', '2019-05-11',
               '2019-05-12', '2019-05-13', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-15',
               '2019-05-16', '2019-05-17'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=137, freq='D')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that only requires built-in libraries.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'

td = timedelta(days=1)

def date_range(end_date, start_date):
    ed = datetime.strptime(end_date, date_fmt)
    sd = datetime.strptime(start_date, date_fmt)

    d = sd
    dates = []
    while d >= ed:
        dates.append(d.strftime(date_fmt))
        d -= td

    return dates
```

This should give you the all the days between the start date and end date, inclusive, in the format `YYYY-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

def get_all_date_from_now_this_year(start):
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d")
    result = []
    while today >= start:
        result.append(start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        start = start + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return result


start = "2019-01-01"
print(get_all_date_from_now_this_year(start))
```

**Output:**

```
['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', ....'2019-05-15', '2019-05-16', '2019-05-17']
```